# HTML: Title in the middle of the box

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the text My homepage in the middle of the box I made. I saw an example on a web site but this does not work properly, as the text is on the left. How can I fix the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>
My homepage
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  margin-left: 20%; 
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: ???px; position: relative; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<h1 id="begin"> My homepage </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: In the middle horizontally, vertically or both?

Comment: I would like to have it horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see also: [Block-level and inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>My homepage</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also recommend reading: [Descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors), [Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) and [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: The outer div is not required, as `<h1>` is a block level element itself

Comment: The point is that that `<div>` is not needed though (and `#begin {...}` would work just as well, and highlight that the `<div>` is not used.)

Answer (score 1):

One simple line of CSS:

```
#container > h1 { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<h1>` is a block level element, so you can simply style it with text-align in your CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>
My homepage
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  margin-left: 20%; 
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="begin"> My homepage </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting all text to be centered at the beginning and decide later what you want not centered,

```
* {    text-align: center;    
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;   
  }
```

you could also center some or all elements at the beginning with the universal selector (*). 
Or fix initially any propoerty that is very common on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply style h1 with css text-align :

```
text-align: center;
```

You don't need to wrap your h1 into div because h1 is a block level element

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/Ltqyfwn0/